# Same error when using any intel command

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, gpu

I have an `Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620` graphics card.
Whenever I try commands like `sudo intel_backlight` or `sudo intel_gpu_top` I get the same error:

```
(intel_gpu_top:1308) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function intel_mmio_use_pci_bar, file ../../lib/intel_mmio.c:145:
(intel_gpu_top:1308) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Failed assertion: !(error != 0)
(intel_gpu_top:1308) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Last errno: 1, Operation not permitted
(intel_gpu_top:1308) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Couldn't map MMIO region
Stack trace:
  #0 [_init+0x7b87]
  #1 [_init+0x5420]
  #2 [_init+0xe85]
  #3 [__libc_start_main+0xe7]
  #4 [_init+0x1c92]
Test (null) failed.
**** DEBUG ****
(intel_gpu_top:1308) intel-chipset-DEBUG: Test requirement passed: pci_dev
(intel_gpu_top:1308) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function intel_mmio_use_pci_bar, file ../../lib/intel_mmio.c:145:
(intel_gpu_top:1308) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Failed assertion: !(error != 0)
(intel_gpu_top:1308) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Last errno: 1, Operation not permitted
(intel_gpu_top:1308) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Couldn't map MMIO region
(intel_gpu_top:1308) igt-core-INFO: Stack trace:
(intel_gpu_top:1308) igt-core-INFO:   #0 [_init+0x7b87]
(intel_gpu_top:1308) igt-core-INFO:   #1 [_init+0x5420]
(intel_gpu_top:1308) igt-core-INFO:   #2 [_init+0xe85]
(intel_gpu_top:1308) igt-core-INFO:   #3 [__libc_start_main+0xe7]
(intel_gpu_top:1308) igt-core-INFO:   #4 [_init+0x1c92]
****  END  ****
FAIL (-1.000s)
```

why is this happening?

Comment: you have secure boot enabled.

Comment: should I disable it? is that a good idea?

Comment: @RinzwinD I went ahead and [disabled the secure boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/618228). Hopefully there won't be any  negative consequences

Comment: It is something we all did ;-) secure boot is a microsoft thing that locks down looking up and altering bios settings unless you have a signed key to access it.